# Google thinks my home page IS a trailing slash

Tags: redirect, google-analytics, directory, google-search-console

I am desperate to know why Google webmaster tools AND analytics are registering my home page as a trailing slash?!

There are no crawl errors, 401s, search issues, nothing wrong otherwise.

My home page is written with a trailing slash and if a visitor does not include the slash, my site will automatically fetch the / and send them to http://about/

I think maybe this is why Google now thinks that / is my home page.

I have a wordpress blog that someone installed but it's my own domain. Has this ever happened to *anyone* in the history of the internet before?

Comment: Sounds like a question for Google, in all honesty.

Comment: There were much more incredible stories in the history of Internet than this one.

Comment: Aww, you edited out all the redundant question marks and exclamation marks. Without them the claim sounds much less credulous.

Comment: What do you mean by "is a trailing slash" anyway? Sounds like a configuration error in the html/server-side code to me.

Comment: What did you expect Google to register your home page URL as?! (I guess we'll never know.)

Answer (score 2):

If you mean Google is showing your site as

```
http://example.com/
```

instead of

```
http://example.com/index.htm
```

then this is to do with the way webservers work.  The server is typically configured to answer a request for the first URL with a default document (which may well be index.htm, depending on your setup).

Additionally, if your site is redirecting visitors to different page with Javascript, you should be aware that Google's search bots typically cannot interpret Javascript, and will not be redirected like a visitor with a graphical browser such as Internet Explorer or Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

As Colin mentioned, this depends on the settings in your webserver and your .htaccess rules. Wordpress typically rewrites URLs (for clean URLs) and it could be misconfiguration there.